# in c++ when i declare an integer variable int a = 200L or int a = 200F or int a = 200U, It allows. How does this happen?

Tags: c++, integer

Basically an integer variable should allow only integer values to be set for its variable. Then how come such special words as follows are allowed?

```
int a = 200L;
int a = 200U;
int a = 200F;
```

I found this when i run the program, it ran perfectly without giving any error. Other letters are not allowed as expected. But why these?

Comment: Please get a text book first before trying to run some code. This is too basic.

Comment: I am new to programming, actually.

Comment: That's exactly why you should start with a good book. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Okay. but can you tell me the answer anyway?

Comment: U L F : integer-suffix http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: Look, what happens is that you are telling the IDE to convert the value into a different type of data.

Answer (score -1):

L, U and F means long, unsigned and float respectively.
so, the code means

```
int a = (long) 200;
int a = (unsigned) 200;
int a = (float) 200;
```

Comment: The question is **why is the initialization allowed**, not what type does the constant have.

Comment: Exactly!! Also what is the data type of variable a at the end?  Is it "int" or "long/unsigned/float"  whatever on the right hand side?

Answer (score -1):

What you do is called implicit conversion.

If you are using gcc compiler you can add

```
-Wconversion
```

(not part of -Wall) option to check any implicit conversion that may alter the value.
Without any option, conversion from signed to unsigned is not warned by default. So you need to active

```
-Wsign-conversion
```

If you want an explicit conversion, it will not be warned by those 2 options.

```
int percent = (int)((int)4.1)*.5;
```

Answer (score -1):

Two different things are going on here.

1) Some letters when stuck on the end of a number take on meaning.  'l' is for long, 'u' is for unsigned, and 'f' is for float.

- "Long" is generally 64 bits wide vs int's 32 bits... but that can
  vary wildly from machine to machine.  DO NOT depend on bit width of
  int and long.
- "Unsigned" means it doesn't bother to track positive or
  negative values... assuming everything is positive.  This about
  doubles how high an integer can go.  Look up "two's complement" for
  further information.
- "Float" means "floating point".  Non whole numbers.  1.5, 3.1415, etc.  They can be very large, or very precise, but not both.  Floats ARE 32 bits.  "Double" is a 64-bit floating point value, which can permit some extreme values of size or precision.

2) Type Coercion, pronounced "co ER shun".

The compiler knows how to convert (coerce) from long to int, unsigned to int, or float to int.  They're all just numbers, right?  Note that converting from float to into "truncates" (drops) anything after a decimal place.  `((int)3.00000001) == 3`.  `((int)2.9999999) == 2`

If you dial your warnings up to max sensitivity, I believe those statements will all trigger warnings because all those conversions could potentially lose data... though the exact phrasing of that warning will vary from compiler to compiler.

***Bonus Information:***

You can trigger this same behavior (accidentally) with classes.

```
struct Foo {
  Foo(int bar) {...}
};
Foo baz = 42;
```

The compiler will treat the above constructor as an option when looking to convert from int to Foo.  The compiler is willing to hop through more than one hoop to get there... so `Foo qux = 3.14159;` would also compile.  This is also true of other class constructors... so if you have some other class that takes a foo as it's only constructor param, you can declare a variable of that class and assign it something that can be coerced to a foo... and so on:

```
struct Corge {
  Corge(Foo foo) {...}
};
corge grault = 1.2345; // you almost certainly didn't intend what will happen here
```

That's three layers of coercion.  double to int, into to foo, and foo to corge.  Bleh!
You can block this with the `explicit` keyword:

```
struct Foo {
  explicit Foo(int bar) {...}
};
Foo baz = 1; // won't compile
```

I wish they'd made `explicit` the default and used some keyword to define conversion constructors instead, but that change would almost certainly break someone's code, so it'll never happen.

Answer (score -2):

What happens is that you are telling the compiler to convert the value into a different type of data. That is to say:

```
int a = 200L; // It's like saying: Hey C++, convert this whole to Long
int a = 200U; // And this to Unsigned
int a = 200F; // And this one to Float
```

There is no error because the compiler understands that these letters at the end indicate a type of conversion.